# azure automation: 'Invoke-ProcessASDatabase' is not recognized

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I am trying to use runbook in Azure automation account to process Azure Analysis Service cube.

I followed Microsoft blog https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-gallery.

However I got following error message when testing it. My runbook script is as following: Can you please help?

**Runbook Script:**

```
$SPCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "TestCred"

$null = Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -databasename "SalesCube" -server "asazure://xx" -RefreshType "Full" -Credential $SPCredential 

Write-Output "Done"
```

**error message:**

> Invoke-ProcessASDatabase : The term 'Invoke-ProcessASDatabase' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
>       script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
>       correct and try again.
>       At line:5 char:9
>       + $null = Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -databasename "SalesCube" -ser ...
>       +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-ProcessASDatabase:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue. We reported this thread to Microsoft this morning.

The following answer is coming from a Microsoft Azure manager:

> An issue has been identified with the .Net version for Azure
>   Automation sandboxes that released a lower version then what was used
>   previously. An update is rolling out to support .Net 4.6 that should
>   resolve issues with PowerShell modules depending on a version on or
>   above .Net 4.5. It is currently planned to be rolled out to all
>   regions by next Monday (the 5th).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with Azure Automation this morning. I have a runbook that has completed successfully for weeks and today it failed with the same error message the OP reported. I've opened a support ticket with MS. If it is a widespread problem, perhaps they will have a fix soon.
--mf